# Move UIButtons when tapped

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uibutton, cgpoint

So I have a scrollable tab bar of UIButtons and I want the tapped button to move to the center of the tab bar when tapped. I have everything set up I just can't figure out how to have the selected button move.

Currently I can dictate a specific button in my method and it will work, but I need it to work for several buttons.

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIScrollView *tabBarScrollView;

@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *btn_1;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *btn_2;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *btn_3;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *btn_4;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *btn_5;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *btn_6;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *btn_7;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *btn_8;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *btn_9;
```

...

```
- (void) buttonAnimation{
    [UIView animateWithDuration:(TAB_BAR_ANIMATION_TIME / 2) animations:^{
        CGPoint moveToCenter = CGPointMake(self.btn_1.frame.origin.x +130, 0);
        [self.tabBarScrollView setContentOffset:moveToCenter];
    }];
}
```

What would be a better math solution for my CGPoint moveToCenter?

Comment: So you're not using a scroll view to enable the scrolling?

Comment: @Wain Yes I do and all the buttons work correctly on it. I've updated the code to reflect the tab bar property.

Answer (score 0):

you could do the following when you instantiate the buttons (for each button):

```
[button addTarget:self action:@selector(doSomething:) forControlEvents: UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

and :

```
-(IBAction)doSomething:(id) sender {
     UIButton *btn = (UIButton *)sender;
    [UIView animateWithDuration:(TAB_BAR_ANIMATION_TIME / 2) animations:^{
        CGPoint moveToCenter = CGPointMake(btn.frame.origin.x +130, 0);
        [self.tabBarScrollView setContentOffset:moveToCenter];
    }];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should first connect ALL your UIButtons to a *single* `IBAction`, then apply animation on the button, the action is invoked for:

Here is an untested code to give you an idea:

```
- (IBAction) buttonAnimation:(id)sender
{
    CGRect screenFrame  = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];
    UIButton *btn = ((UIButton *)sender).frame;
    CGpoint centerpoint = CGPoint((screenFrame.size.width / 2) - btn.size.width / 2, btn.origin.y); 
    [UIView animateWithDuration:(TAB_BAR_ANIMATION_TIME / 2) 
                     animations:^{
        [self.tabBarScrollView setContentOffset:moveToCenter];
    }];
}
```

Comment: Yeah I have it all connected in the code my issue is the

Comment: @HectorLopez, your statements is incomplete. Didn't get you :(